# Adding text to pandas pie charts

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Below are the 3 pie charts that are created using python pandas. It has 2 labels that are displayed on their side. I want to add the text  "Total lines = 1000" that has to be displayed above the labels.
I am not pretty sure on how this text can be added above labels in pie chart.

Current code:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches


 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
 fig.show()

 val1 = len(df_1) - len(df_result12)
 val2 = len(df_result12)
 if (val2 == 0):
  ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3),(0,0))
  values = [val1]
  plt.pie(df_32, colors = "g", autopct=make_autopct(values))
  plt.title('FIG1',fontsize = 25)

  val3 = len(df_2) - len(df_result22)
  val4 = len(df_result22)
  if (val4 == 0):
   ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3),(0,1))
   values = [val3]
   plt.pie(df_5res, colors=("g"), autopct=make_autopct(values))
   plt.title('FIG2',fontsize = 25)


 yellow_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='yellow', label='Yes')
 green_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='green', label='No')
 plt.legend(handles=[yellow_patch,green_patch], bbox_to_anchor=(6, 3),prop={'size':30})
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated !!

Comment: have you tried `fig.suptitle`?

Comment: @M.T: This was the property I was looking for. Thanks !!